# XSL to flatten a nested list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is the opposite of a question I asked a couple of months ago. I have a nested structure that I need to flatten. For example, the input might be something like this:

```
<root>
  <h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2 
              <ol>
            <li>sub-num1</li>
            <li>sub-num2                     
                      <ol>
                <li>sub-sub-num1</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
              </ol>
        </li>
        <li>num3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

And the output should be flattened as follows:

```
<root>
   <h1>text</h1>
   <list level="1">num1</list>
   <list level="1">num2</list>
   <list level="2">sub-num1</list>
   <list level="2">sub-num2</list>
   <list level="3">sub-sub-num1</list>
   <list level="1">num3</list>
   <p>text</p>
   <list level="1">num1</list>
   <list level="1">num2</list>
   <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

I think I could do it in a un-elegant way, but I was hoping someone might have a better method to share. This needs to be done using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <list level="{count(ancestor::ol)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ol)]"/>
        </list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ol"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">num1</list>
    <list level="1">num2                
    </list>
    <list level="2">sub-num1</list>
    <list level="2">sub-num2                                            
    </list>
    <list level="3">sub-sub-num1</list>
    <list level="1">num3</list>
    <p>text</p>
    <list level="1">num1</list>
    <list level="1">num2</list>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

Comment: +1. Beat me for seconds. Though our answers are just slightly different.

Comment: +1 to both you and @Flack. But people, It seems to me that Jim's solution is more efficient.

Comment: @Dimitre: Yes. I also agree that parameterized numbering is more efficient. Although I also prefer applying templates to string value for `list` content.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this with Oxygen/XML and your input.  You didn't specify what you wanted to occur if the nested OL had text both before and after; in this case all the text will be output before the nested items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ol">
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="li">
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <list level="{$level}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join(text(),' '))"/></list>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ol">
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's XSLT 2.0. The OP did specify it needs to done using XSLT 1.0

Comment: @Flynn1179: It can be easily refactored into an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet.

Comment: I've no doubt it can, but if the OP doesn't have experience of XSLT2, she may not know how.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0** solution you asked for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <list level="{count(ancestor::li) + 1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct result against your sample is:

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">num1</list>
    <list level="1">num2</list>
    <list level="2">sub-num1</list>
    <list level="2">sub-num2</list>
    <list level="3">sub-sub-num1</list>
    <list level="1">num3</list>
    <p>text</p>
    <list level="1">num1</list>
    <list level="1">num2</list>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim, you got me on the right track. I modified your stylesheet somewhat as I need to apply templates within the `<li>` elements. I also removed the level parameter as this value can be obtained by counting the ancestors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::ol)">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <list level="{count(ancestor::ol)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ol" mode="passThrough"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol" mode="passThrough">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 Good self answer. Check mine to see why the two rules for `ol` are not needed.